# How can I rotate the individual triangles in a WebGL tessellation?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

The purpose of my code is to individually rotate the four triangles that make up a tessellated triangle. Currently, it rotates the entire tessellation as if it is one object. I do not want it do do this. How can I rotate the individual triangles?

Here's the output:

[image: output]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
<title>2D Sierpinski Gasket</title>


<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 vPosition;
uniform float theta;

void
main()
{
    float s = sin( theta );
    float c = cos( theta );

    gl_Position.x = -s * vPosition.y + c * vPosition.x;
    gl_Position.y =  s * vPosition.x + c * vPosition.y;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gasket2.js"></script>
</head>   

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var canvas;
var gl;

var points = [];

var theta = 0.0;
var thetaLoc;

var NumTimesToSubdivide = 5;

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    //
    //  Initialize our data for the Sierpinski Gasket
    //

    // First, initialize the corners of our gasket with three points.

    var vertices = [
        vec2( -1, -1 ),
        vec2(  0,  1 ),
        vec2(  1, -1 )
    ];

    divideTriangle( vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2],
                    NumTimesToSubdivide);

    //
    //  Configure WebGL
    //
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    // Load the data into the GPU

    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    // Associate our shader variables with our data buffer

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "theta" );

    render();
};

function triangle( a, b, c )
{
    points.push( a, b, c );
}

function divideTriangle( a, b, c, count )
{
    // check for end of recursion

    if ( count === 0 ) {
        triangle( a, b, c );
    }
    else {

        //bisect the sides

        var ab = mix( a, b, 0.5 );
        var ac = mix( a, c, 0.5 );
        var bc = mix( b, c, 0.5 );

        --count;

        // three new triangles

        divideTriangle( a, ab, ac, count );
        divideTriangle( c, ac, bc, count );
        divideTriangle( b, bc, ab, count );
        divideTriangle( ac, bc, ab, count );
    }
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    theta += 45;
    gl.uniform1f( thetaLoc, theta );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, points.length );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotating each individual triangle usually means rotating it about its *centroid*, which requires knowing the coordinates of the triangle's other two points, and a vertex shader processes only one vertex at a time. (Usually, points are rotated about the *origin*.) One solution is to calculate each triangle's centroid and to add the centroid as an additional per-vertex attribute alongside each vertex position.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. Change your initial vertices to: -0.5,-0.5,0.0,0.5,0.5,-0.5 and convert theta to radians in vertex shader.